# Page not save forms data in django

Tags: python, django, forms, save

I am trying to do exercise 7 in tango with django where i must save new page to specific category by adding information to forms.

So I write new code to forms.py

```
class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the title of the page.")
    url = forms.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Please enter the url of the page.")
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)

    class Meta:
        model = Page

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        url = cleaned_data.get('url')

        if url and not url.startswith('http//'):
            url = 'http://' + url
            cleaned_data['url'] = url
        return cleaned_data       

        fields = ('title', 'url', 'views')  

    def save_form(self):
        if self.is_valid():
            page = self.save(commit=False)
            try:
                cat = Category.objects.get(name=category_name)
                page.category = cat
            except:
                return render_to_response('rango/add_category.html', {}, context)
            page.views = 0
            page.save()

            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Then I edit views.py

```
def add_page(request, category_name_url):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    category_name = decode_url(category_name_url)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PageForm(request.POST)
        if form.save_form():
           return category(request, category_name_url)
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = PageForm()

    return render_to_response( 'rango/add_page.html',
            {'category_name_url': category_name_url,
             'category_name': category_name,
             'form': form},
             context)

def decode_url(element):
    return element.replace(' ', '_')

def encode_url(element):
    return element.replace('_', '')
```

Then I created template:

> Rango
>
> ```
> <body>
>     <h1>Add page to category</h1>
>
>     <form id="page_form" method="post" action="/">
>
>         {% csrf_token %}
>         {% for hidden in forms.hidden_fields %}
>             {{ hidden }}
>         {% endfor %}
>
>         {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
>             {{ field.errors }}
>             {{ field.help_text }}
>             {{ field }}
>         {% endfor %}
>
>         <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add a page" />
>     </form>
> </body> </html>
> ```

I have made reference to new page in category.html

```
<a href="/rango/category/{{ category_name_url }}/add_page/">Add page to this category</a>
```

And of course a edit urls.py

```
> url(r'^rango/category/(?P<category_name_url>\w+)/add_page/$',
> views.add_page, name='add_page'),
```

Everything is visible and I am able to fill form. But when i confirm data by clicking on button, page is return to home and not in category and new page is not save in database. So please someone, where a have error?

Answer (score 2):

Your `<form>` element has the action set to `action="/"`. This makes the form submit send a POST request to the homepage not the current page. You can correct this by making the form action empty `action=""` to submit to the current URL or be explicit and use the `{% url %}` template tag for the required form action.

Comment: Thanks Mark for reply. I tried your advice and now after submit data I stayed on add_page page, but nothing has to save :-( So I must have some more error code :-(